# What is clf and legend in 'plot_decision_regions'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, knn, mlxtend

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

def knn_comparision(data, k):
    X = data[['x1','x2']].values
    y = data['y'].astype(int).values
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plotting decision regions
    plot_decision_regions(X, y, clf=clf, legend=2)
```

What are the parameters '**clf**' and '**legend**' in plot_decision_regions?

Comment: http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/api_subpackages/mlxtend.plotting/#plot_decision_regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clf` is the classifier object being returned from `neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier`, which is likely coming from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html).

BigBen linked the documentation already for the [`plot_decision_regions`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/api_subpackages/mlxtend.plotting/#plot_decision_regions) function, which explains what they do.